# Kendo asp .net MVC not showing records on kendo grid

Tags: ajax, kendo-asp.net-mvc

cshtml File: (home.cshtml)

```
 @using Kendo.Mvc.UI;


    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Welcome to Kendo UI!</title>
        <!-- Common Kendo UI CSS for web widgets and widgets for data visualization. -->
        <link href="~/Kendo/styles/kendo.common.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <!-- (Optional) RTL CSS for Kendo UI widgets for the web. Include only in right-to-left applications. -->
        <link href="~/Kendo/styles/kendo.rtl.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <!-- Default Kendo UI theme CSS for web widgets and widgets for data visualization. -->
        <link href="~/Kendo/styles/kendo.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

        <!-- (Optional) Kendo UI Hybrid CSS. Include only if you will use the mobile devices features. -->
        <link href="~/Kendo/styles/kendo.default.mobile.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

        <!-- jQuery JavaScript -->
        <script src="~/Kendo/js/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <!-- Kendo UI combined JavaScript -->
        <script src="~/Kendo/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<MiCustomerSentiment.UserProfile>()
        .Name("divSearchResult")
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource // Configure the grid data source
          .Ajax() // Specify that ajax binding is used
          .Read(read => read.Action("Products_Read", "Home"))
        )
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
          columns.Bound(user => user.FirstName);
          columns.Bound(user => user.LastName);
          columns.Bound(user => user.EmployeeId);
          columns.Bound(user => user.UserName);
        })
        .Pageable() // Enable paging
        .Sortable() // Enable sorting
        )
    </body>
    </html>
```

Backend action method in the controller:

```
 using Kendo.Mvc.UI;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using MiCustomerSentiment.Models;
    using Kendo.Mvc.Extensions;

    namespace MiCustomerSentiment.Controllers
    {
        public class HomeController : Controller
        {
            public ActionResult Home()
            {
                return View();
            }

                [HttpGet]
            public ActionResult Products_Read([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
            {
                using (var _db = new SampleData())
                {
                    IQueryable<UserProfile> unitslist = _db.UserProfiles;
                    DataSourceResult result = unitslist.ToDataSourceResult(request);
                    return Json(result,JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Model: (UserProfile.cs)

```
namespace MiCustomerSentiment
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

    [Table("support.UserProfile")]
    public class UserProfile
    {
        [Key]
        public int UserId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "First Name is required")]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }


        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last Name is required")]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }


        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Employee Id is required")]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string EmployeeId { get; set; }


        [Required(ErrorMessage = "UserName is required")]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        public bool? IsActive { get; set; }
        public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }

        public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Thanks for youer help!

1. Tried with all links which had similar issues. But could not get any answer for my problem.
2. tried adding JsonBehavior.Allowget in the controller action methos.
3. Tried adding [httpget] verb.

Expected Result: Data has to be shown in grid.

Comment: That's almost a perfect question. The only problem is: What is your problem? What happens? Are there any error messages in the JavaScript console of the browser?

Comment: @CarstenFranke I am getting following error in console -- Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).kendoGrid is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (Home:69)
    at mightThrow (VM2871 jquery-3.3.1.js:3534)
    at process (VM2871 jquery-3.3.1.js:3602)

Comment: Are you sure that the paths to the JS (and CSS) files are correct?

Comment: @CarstenFranke Verified the paths again. They are correct only !